# Create K-mer from Connections

Tags: python, pandas, graph-theory

My first question. Couldn't think of any good title :(  Please pardon me of any mistakes.

**Data:**
I have a matrix (pandas dataframe) from scipy cdist which is the distance between the points. x,y == y,x . Diagonal is 0.

The scipy cdist gives a matrix (all_dists) which looks like this:

- Too many columns and rows, paste sites rejected the whole data.

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.000000 | 3.820418 | 6.939914 | 10.394031 | 12.986421 | 15.954358 | 18.466566 | 17.150426 |
| 1 | 3.820418 | 0.000000 | 3.808182 | 6.768351 | 9.546234 | 12.570400 | 14.821706 | 13.363969 |
| 2 | 6.939914 | 3.808182 | 0.000000 | 3.801501 | 6.281040 | 9.015788 | 11.679313 | 10.835315 |
| 3 | 10.394031 | 6.768351 | 3.801501 | 0.000000 | 3.803191 | 6.066118 | 8.078145 | 7.233544 |
| 4 | 12.986421 | 9.546234 | 6.281040 | 3.803191 | 0.000000 | 3.798256 | 6.464700 | 5.730587 |
| 5 | 15.954358 | 12.570400 | 9.015788 | 6.066118 | 3.798256 | 0.000000 | 3.813902 | 5.525810 |
| 6 | 18.466566 | 14.821706 | 11.679313 | 8.078145 | 6.464700 | 3.813902 | 0.000000 | 3.806409 |
| 7 | 17.150426 | 13.363969 | 10.835315 | 7.233544 | 5.730587 | 5.525810 | 3.806409 | 0.000000 |

I need to create two types of groups (separate functions) based on cutoff and size.
Let's say cutoff is 10.0 and size is 5.

1. **Linear** form:

   - If we start from 0 take all connected indexes to 0 within cutoff. Let's say we get 1, 2, 12
   - Now we have connections  0-1  ,  0-2  , 0-12
   - Take next connected from 1 (0,2,3,10,11,12) , 2 (0, 1, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 272) and 12 (0, 1, 2, 11, 13, 14, 15, 47, 48)
   - This now gives me:  0-1-2 , 0-1-3, 0-1-10,  0-1-11 ,...... , 0-2-4, 0-2-10, .... 0-12-13 etc
   - This is of size 3. So on extend till the size 5 is achieved. All such combos for each index. Above is for 0, then for 1, then 2 and till the end.
2. **Globular** Form:

   - All 5 indices are within cutoff from each other. Basically all 5 should be present in each other.
   - In above example  0-1-10 .  The 10 also needs to be within cutoff from 0. or 10 should be connection of 0, which in this case is not so can't form this combo.

**Rule:**

1. Index cannot be repeated within a combo. 21-17-18-21  is invalid as 21 is repeated
2. The order of indices in output matters in 1st type,  but is meaningless in 2nd type.

I converted the data into the form of dictionary as connections here:

https://paste.debian.net/1199163/

Looks like:

```
0   [1, 2, 12]
1   [0, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13]
2   [0, 1, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 272]
3   [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]
4   [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 197, 272]
5   [3, 4, 6, 7, 170, 171, 195, 196, 197]
6   [4, 5, 7, 8, 170, 195, 196]
7   [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 149, 170]
8   [3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
9   [3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11]
10  [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11]
```

**Output**

- For each combo, List with 5 elements
- Such list of lists is also good.
- Any other format where I can easily access each group of 5 is also acceptable.

Here are 310 points.  Worst case: 4000 points.
Recursion seems to be not good idea.

Thank You

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Simply, how to get all connections of size 5 for all points.

Comment: It looks like you have already succeeded in doing so.  The debian link appears to have the result.  All that needs to be done is go through that table and pick out the lines that have five connections.

Comment: I think there is small missing. eg:  If 1 is connected to 5 others (11,12,13,14,15). That's not the answer. The answer is what is 11 is connected to. Forming connection 1->11->24  . Now what is this 24 connected to making 1->11->24->31  . Next for 31, making it 1->11->24->31->54  . This is one combo of 5 elements. Similarly 1 is connected to 12. Form those connections. Even 11, 12 are connected to multiple points so those combos will also be there. Imagine it like a tree of size 5 nodes. Starting from end node moving to first all possible links should be reported.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can make out, you want to display all paths from every node to every node that are exactly 5 hops long.

Algorithm:

- Convert your table into the normal format for specifying the links in a graph

So

```
0   [1, 2, 12]
1   [0, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

becomes

```
1 2
1 12
0 2
0 3
0 10
0 11
0 12
0 13
```

- Read the links into any graph library ( I use boost::graph ) with every link cost set to 1
- Loop over nodes to get source node

  - Run the Dijsktra algorithm. ( This gives the path and cost from the source node to every other node )
  - Loop over other nodes to get destination node

    - if cost from source to destination equals 5, print path

Implementing this algorithm in C++ using the [PathFinder wrapper](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder) for boost::graph

```
void cPathFinder::gsingh()
{
    //loop over source nodes
    for (int src = 0; src < nodeCount(); src++)
    {
        // Run Dijsktra
        myStart = src;
        paths(src);

        // loop over destination nodes
        for (int dst = 0; dst < nodeCount(); dst++)
        {
            if (src == dst)
                continue;

            // display paths that visit 5 nodes
            if (pathPick(dst).size() == 5)
                std::cout << pathText();
        }
    }
}
```

output is for first two source nodes

```
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 149
1 -> 13 -> 15 -> 17 -> 18
1 -> 13 -> 15 -> 276 -> 277
1 -> 13 -> 15 -> 17 -> 19
1 -> 13 -> 15 -> 17 -> 52
1 -> 13 -> 15 -> 276 -> 278
1 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 38
1 -> 12 -> 48 -> 43 -> 39
1 -> 12 -> 48 -> 43 -> 40
1 -> 12 -> 48 -> 43 -> 41
1 -> 12 -> 48 -> 43 -> 44
1 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 284
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 80 -> 81
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 77 -> 74
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 77 -> 75
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 77 -> 76
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 80 -> 118
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 80 -> 117
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 80 -> 119
1 -> 11 -> 49 -> 80 -> 120
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 150
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 151
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 152
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 170 -> 168
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 169
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 172
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 173
1 -> 13 -> 274 -> 200 -> 174
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 171 -> 198
1 -> 13 -> 274 -> 200 -> 175
1 -> 13 -> 274 -> 200 -> 176
1 -> 13 -> 14 -> 275 -> 201
1 -> 13 -> 274 -> 200 -> 202
1 -> 13 -> 274 -> 200 -> 203
1 -> 13 -> 272 -> 270 -> 188
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 195 -> 191
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 195 -> 192
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 195 -> 193
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 195 -> 194
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 290 -> 259
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 290 -> 262
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 290 -> 263
1 -> 13 -> 272 -> 266 -> 264
1 -> 13 -> 272 -> 266 -> 265
1 -> 13 -> 272 -> 266 -> 267
1 -> 13 -> 272 -> 266 -> 268
1 -> 13 -> 272 -> 270 -> 269
1 -> 13 -> 15 -> 276 -> 287
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 288 -> 285
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 288 -> 286
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 292 -> 294
1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 293 -> 295
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 7 -> 170
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 171
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 195
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 196
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 7 -> 149
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 17 -> 18
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 17 -> 51
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 276 -> 277
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 17 -> 19
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 17 -> 52
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 276 -> 278
0 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 38
0 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 39
0 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 40
0 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 41
0 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 44
0 -> 12 -> 47 -> 42 -> 284
0 -> 12 -> 48 -> 78 -> 79
0 -> 12 -> 48 -> 78 -> 80
0 -> 12 -> 48 -> 77 -> 74
0 -> 12 -> 48 -> 77 -> 75
0 -> 12 -> 48 -> 78 -> 76
0 -> 12 -> 48 -> 78 -> 118
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 197 -> 172
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 197 -> 198
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 273 -> 199
0 -> 1 -> 13 -> 274 -> 200
0 -> 12 -> 14 -> 275 -> 201
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 270 -> 188
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 197 -> 191
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 270 -> 192
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 266 -> 262
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 266 -> 263
0 -> 1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 290
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 266 -> 264
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 266 -> 265
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 266 -> 267
0 -> 1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 293
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 266 -> 268
0 -> 2 -> 272 -> 270 -> 269
0 -> 12 -> 15 -> 276 -> 287
0 -> 12 -> 14 -> 288 -> 285
0 -> 12 -> 14 -> 288 -> 286
0 -> 1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 289
0 -> 1 -> 13 -> 291 -> 292
```

FYI there are a total of 12,546 paths of length`5 nodes